# Mips SLL operator

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to implement 2^15 and decrement by 1 with lls. I am basically trying to do 2^15,2^14,etc. and then print that value. However, i am having trouble and I can't figure out why. It stops after two iterations because it goes to 0. the output is (32768  16384   0   -16384  -32768  -49152  -65536  -81920 etc) Any suggestions? Thank you

```
   addi $s1, $zero, 2

Loop2:
beqz $s1, end2 #if 15 reches 0 than end
sll $t1, $s1, 14
#decrement by 1
addi $s1,$s1,-1


#add 1 into $v0 print
addi $v0, $zero, 1

#move ($s0) into $a0
move $a0, $t1

syscall
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sll $t1, $s1, 2` in this case means `$t1 = $s1 << 2`, which is just multiplying `$s1` by 4. To do `^15` you probably want to do

```
addi $s1, $zero, 2
sll $t1, $s1, 14
```

### For the edited question

This is my solution to it:

```
addi $s1, $zero, 2  # base is 2
sll $t1, $s1, 14    # $t1 = 2 << 14

Loop2:
addi $v0, $zero, 1  # use print int service
move $a0, $t1       # load $t1 into argument
syscall

srl $t1, $t1, 1     # shift right, effectively decrement the exp by 1

bnez $t1, Loop2     # loop until $t1 is zero
```

Here is a few major things I changed:

- moved `beqz $s1, end2 #if 15 reches 0 than end` to the end of the loop and flipped the logic.

  - the idea is you want to go back up unless the result becomes 0. Not sure if the `end2` is another label or just a typo, but you want to have something branch back to the beginning of the loop.
- `addi $s1,$s1,-1` is actually changing the base, not the exponent.

  - so what you had was basically 2 << 14, 1 << 14, 0 << 14, -1 << 14, etc.
  - to decrease the exponent in this case, all you have to do is unshift (or shift right) the previous result by 1. Hence the `srl $t1, $t1, 1` in my code.

Comment: I knew i had them mixmatched. I made those changes and it goes to two iterations correctly and stops. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a shift by a variable amount, so use `sllv`.

Try something like this, which is assembly code for `1 << n`:

```
li $t0, 1
sllv $t1, $t0, $s1
```

in place of your shift (`sll $t1, $s1, 2`).